# for loop in jinja, flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a function which select the matching data from data set and return it as dict. Function is given below.

```
def Return_details(movie_name):
    t = movie_details.loc[movie_details['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'title']
    imdb = movie_details.loc[movie_details['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'imdb_score']
    g = movie_details.loc[movie_details['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'genre']
    y = movie_details.loc[movie_details['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'year']
    p = movie_details.loc[movie_details['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'poster']
    try:
        title = t.iat[0]
        imdb_score = imdb.iat[0]
        genre = g.iat[0]
        year = y.iat[0]
        link = p.iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        return{'None':'None'}
    else:
        return {'title':movie_name},{'poster':link},{'imdb_score':imdb_score},{'genre':genre},{'year':year}return movie_name,link,imdb_score,genre,year
```

And in the flask app I have create a list which accept this dict and place it inside a list. here is the code for list

```
    list_contains_details = []
    for i in predict:
        list_contains_details.extend(Return_details(i))
        print(list_contains_details)

    return render_template('index.html',data = list_contains_details)
```

inside index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<body>
<div>
    {% for i in data %}
        <p>{{  i.title }} </p><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, it is only printing title which is present at last of the list and rest of the title is not printing. I have also tried with the static list but it is not working, here is the code for it.

```
    data = [{'title':'toy story', 'year':'2018', 'title':'Jumanji','year':'2019'}]
    return render_template('data.html',data=data)
```

data.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<body>
<div>
    {% for i in data %}
        <p>{{  i.title }} </p><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `data` is just a list of one dictionary with same key twice,try this `data = [{'title':'toy story', 'year':'2018'},{'title':'Jumanji','year':'2019'}]`

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, at the point you are defining your "data" variable. The items in data should be separated, data = [{'title':'toy story', 'year':'2018'}, {'title':'Jumanji','year':'2019'}]. Hope this helps!